# How to Configure the Virtual Directory to Require SSL?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am using IIS V5.1
I have wcf service application for which I am using security mode = Transport.
and wshttpbinding.

How can I Configure the Virtual Directory to Require SSL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a server certificate for your web site to enable SSL for a virtual Directory.

See [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=324069) for details about setting up ssl.

You will need to get a server certificate from somewhere you can create a self-signed certificate by following these [instructions](http://huntjason.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9D2E96F2AA6AE85F!413.entry).